# android support library addition issue

Tags: android, eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.first.densgi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Above is the manifest.xml
Below is a copy of the main activity class.

```
package com.first.densgi;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am also attaching 1 screenshot and a of the log, the screenshot is to view all the project folders in the app and the log to capture the error message when trying to add support libraries through android tools. One reply mentioned adding the support-v4.jar to my lib folder. Well from the screenshot you will find that eclipse did not create that folder.

```
Image, Android API 24, revision 19
[2018-03-26 11:45:20 - SDK Manager]     Found Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 25, revision 9
[2018-03-26 11:45:20 - SDK Manager]     Found Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 26, revision 7
[2018-03-26 11:45:20 - SDK Manager]     Found Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 27, revision 3
[2018-03-26 11:45:20 - SDK Manager]     Found Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API P, revision 1
[2018-03-26 11:45:20 - SDK Manager] Done loading packages.
[2018-03-26 11:45:20 - Android Support Jar not found:] C:\Users\Uchenna\Desktop\v4\android-support-v4.jar
```

[view of screen shot of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw74Y.png)

Most suggestion i have online advice using android studio but just installed eclipse and want all my development ie se, ee, web, and mobile to be in one environment.

Pls i feel very bad that the first time i asked a question on this platform no one attempted an answer.

I am still facing the stated issue, i have updated eclipse to oxygen3.a and right now i have an additional issue of not been able to install jboss and wildfly servers. Gives an unhandled event loop exception

Comment: Edit your question with proper problem and proper formatting with sufficient code snippet  which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it is not bescause of wrong SDK location.

put the specific library inside the libs folder inside your android project folder.

Open your app level build.gradle file in android project in eclipse and add library to compile it.
Ex; compile 'com.ajts.androidmads.SQLite2Excel:library:1.0.2'

then sync the eclipse project.